# Make Play! Framework "play" nice with source control

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, netbeans, playframework

I'm using Play! Framework and Netbeans as my IDE, so that means that I've used

```
play netbeansify
```

to generate the appropriate project files for netbeans. However, I've noticed that this generates only absolute urls everywhere pointing to the different Play! assets, instead of relative urls. Is there some way of having netbeansify generate a Netbeans project that doesn't use absolute urls and thus plays nicely with source control and working with other people?

Comment: lol, I, for one, won't be Play!ing with that toy anytime soon ;)

Comment: Why on earth do you want to keep IDE-specific files in version control?

Comment: What is wrong with each developer checking out the project and eclipsifying or netbeansifying or idealizing it as he wants? That way , what is in the repository is IDE independent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. The idea of the playframework core team is, that the generate file shouldn't commited. If you use svn or cvs you will run into trouble if you commit.
You can try a feature request, so that the people see there are more people which found it useful.

Comment: I created a ticket in the play framework issue tracker: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/459-netbeans-project-paths-generated-by-netbeansify-should-be-relative